# umbraco cms physical/real path of media folder

Tags: umbraco

I have installed umbraco cms and I'm just trying to figure it out where are stored the "media" files uploaded . Basically I can see them delivered through a kind of url rewrite on the web like http://domain.com/media/4554/file.extension. However I would like to know where are actually located the files on the disk .  I would appreciate any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media files should in '/media' in the root directory of wherever you installed the site. Umbraco doesn't do any URL-rewriting for media uploads.